# Add multiple line items in an invoice In open-source QuickBooks PHP DevKit

Tags: quickbooks

I am using the open-source QuickBooks PHP DevKit on GitHub. I added an invoice against a customer using the example "example_invoice_add.php" and added one line. How can I add multiple line items in an invoice using the same example at a time. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a second (and third, and forth, and fifth, and etc.) line item is exactly like adding the first line item.

Create the `Line` object, and then call `$Invoice->addLine($Line)`.

Example:

```
// First line item
$Line = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Line();
$Line->setDetailType('SalesItemLineDetail');
$Line->setAmount(12.95 * 2);
$Line->setDescription('Here is my first line item.');

$SalesItemLineDetail = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_SalesItemLineDetail();
$SalesItemLineDetail->setItemRef('8');
$SalesItemLineDetail->setUnitPrice(12.95);
$SalesItemLineDetail->setQty(2);

$Line->addSalesItemLineDetail($SalesItemLineDetail);

$Invoice->addLine($Line); // Add the line item


// Now let's do the exact same thing again, to add the second line item 
$Line = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Line();
$Line->setDetailType('SalesItemLineDetail');
$Line->setAmount(12.95 * 2);
$Line->setDescription('Here is my *SECOND* line item.');

$SalesItemLineDetail = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_SalesItemLineDetail();
$SalesItemLineDetail->setItemRef('8');
$SalesItemLineDetail->setUnitPrice(12.95);
$SalesItemLineDetail->setQty(2);

$Line->addSalesItemLineDetail($SalesItemLineDetail);

$Invoice->addLine($Line); // Add the line item 


// Hrm, let's keep going. Add another line item by doing the exact same thing again...
$Line = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Line();
$Line->setDetailType('SalesItemLineDetail');
$Line->setAmount(12.95 * 2);
$Line->setDescription('Here is my *THIRD* line item.');

$SalesItemLineDetail = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_SalesItemLineDetail();
$SalesItemLineDetail->setItemRef('8');
$SalesItemLineDetail->setUnitPrice(12.95);
$SalesItemLineDetail->setQty(2);

$Line->addSalesItemLineDetail($SalesItemLineDetail);

$Invoice->addLine($Line);
```